# How to show semi-transparent mask over Listview Items in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to show a layer (Mask) over the list view items.

Basically what I want to do is, I need to make control un-selectable when certain property is set, So I will make upper layer visible to make items non-selectable.

Can Anyone suggest How can I achieve this.
Let me know if any further details are required.

Thanks in Anticipation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put two controls over each other:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView IsEnabled="{Binding ...}" ...>
    <Rectange Opacity="0.5" Visibility="{Binding ...}" ...>
</Grid>
```

You should also disable ListView, because otherwise users will be able to access it with the keyboard.

Comment: The control order within this `Grid` should be reversed. `Grid` Control Layout order is kind of important. right now the Mask would get rendered "behind" the `ListView` instead of above it